# Pandas filter values from multiple columns

Tags: pandas, filter, multiple-columns

I want to find id which has different prod.
Here, The answer would be id-1,2, and 4 coz it has different prod.
 and the answer is not id 3 coz, id 3 has similar prod.

How do I write a program in Python to filter the result?

```
   id prod
0   1    a
1   1    l
2   2    l
3   2    a
4   3    a
5   3    a
6   3    a
7   4    l
8   4    a
```

Comment: Kindly post your samples in text format in your post with CODE TAGS it isnot recommended to post it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(['id','prod'],keep=False),'id']
#or df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)['id']

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
7    4
8    4
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 how about `df.groupby('id')['prod'].apply(lambda x: x.nunique()==len(x))` ?

Comment: Thanks a TON for letting me know here, when I run your suggested code I get error like `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable` any idea on it,I am learning Pandas, sorry if missed something here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 try this `df.loc[df.groupby('id')['prod'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique()==len(x)),'id']` but again, will fail if example is : there is a group of 3 and 2 duplicates

Comment: I am sorry I am still getting an error `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`no I haven't changed any df's value here. I will try to post this question once. Thanks a TON for your help :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 works fine for me. :( okay sure and no problem. :)